# Получение данных из таблиц имеющих связь многие ко многим postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, postgresql

**Входные данные:** PostgreSQL. Есть 3 таблицы: products, colors, products_to_colors. Связь такая - каждый продукт может иметь несколько цветов. Каждый цвет может быть у нескольких продуктов. Связь между цветами и продуктами реализована с помощью 3 таблицы products_to_colors.

**Поля в таблицах:**

1. products - два поля: `id`, `name` (остальные не имеют значение, упрощаем задачу =) )
2. colors - 2 поля: `id`, `color` (в `color` указывается сам цвет, например, зелёный)
3. products_to_colors - 3 поля: `id`, `color_id`, `product_id` (поле `id` наверное тут лишнее, хз зачем я его сделал)

**Задача:** Скорее всего это избитый вопрос и уже кучу постов с подобными вопросами. Но у меня не получилось ничего найти. Задача состоит в том, чтобы одним запросом к БД получить все данные из этих 3 таблиц. Использую `python3` и `asyncpg` (asyncpg - асинхронный postgres для python, можно делать на примере `psycopg2`, я разберусь). [Нашёл статью](http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/9983), как это делается в `mysql`, попытался адаптировать к `postgres`:

```
SELECT products.*, string_agg(colors(color), ',')
FROM products
LEFT JOIN products_to_colors ON products.id = products_to_colors.product_id
LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = products_to_colors.color_id;
```

**Получаю ошибку:**

```
ERROR:  function colors(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT products.*, string_agg(colors(color), ',')
                                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Не понимаю, что хочет от меня `postgres` и как исправить ошибку

**Ещё 1 вопрос:** Также, если я правильно понимаю, то значение colors вернётся мне в виде строки, где значения будут разделены запятыми. Хотелось бы, что это был объект списка python. Возможно такое? Или нужно вручную парсить значения?

Comment: Алиасы таблицы и поля разделяют точкой, а не используют для этого скобки. `string_agg(colors.color, ',')`

Comment: Запрос вернёт скалярное значение - Вы сами об этом просите. Так что парсите полученное на питоновской стороне.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, создам новый вопрос по этому поводу, так же удалю свои ненужные комментарии